# Passing variable from another class as input but not getting value back

Tags: c#, class, return

I have a class where I hold some variables :

```cs
public class PreviousCalls
{
    private static int bot1Call;
    public static int previousBot1Call
    {
        get { return bot1Call; }
        set { bot1Call = value; }
    }

    private static int bot2Call;
    public static int previousBot2Call
    {
        get { return bot2Call; }
        set { bot2Call = value; }
    }

    private static int bot3Call;
    public static int previousBot3Call
    {
        get { return bot3Call; }
        set { bot3Call = value; }
    }

    private static int bot4Call;
    public static int previousBot4Call
    {
        get { return bot4Call; }
        set { bot4Call = value; }
    }

    private static int bot5Call;
    public static int previousBot5Call
    {
        get { return bot5Call; }
        set { bot5Call = value; }
    }
}
```

I need to pass those variables as parameters to a lot of methods in my other class here's how I do it :

```cs
void AI(... , int previous)
AI(... , PreviousCalls.previousBot1Call);
```

So the parameter previous is changing the way it should but the variables from class `PreviousCalls` are not changing at all, why is that ?

Comment: Please also include what the `AI()` method does so that we can better understand your question.

Comment: Well it calculates some things i dont think it's necessary let's say AI just does `previous - 1` .. the variables from PreviousCalls wont change at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is value type, so there is a copy of 'previous value' passed to method body. So changing a variable inside method doesn't cause the original value change:

```
public void Test(int a)
{
   a = 10;
} 

int t = 11;
Test(t);
//t is still 11, because Test method operates on copy of t
```

To change original value you must use `ref` or `out`:

```
void AI(..., ref int previous) { ... }

int param;
AI(..., ref param); //when ref is used, original variable wil be changed.
PreviousCalls.previousBot1Call = param;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use it like this:

```
AI(... , ref PreviousCalls.previousBot1Call); // compile-time error
                                              // member-access is forbidden wtih out/ref
AI(,.., ref 10); // compile-time error
```

**Another attempt:**

```
    interface IAIParam
    {
         int Previous { get; set; }
         // other params
    }

    void AI(IAIParam p)
    {
       p.Previous += 1; 
       //....
    }
```

And then implementaiton:

```
internal class MyBotProxy : IAIParam
{
    public int Previous
    {
        get { return PreviousCalls.previousBot1Call; }
        set { PreviousCalls.previousBot1Call = value; }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
var myProxy = new MyBotProxy();
AI(myProxy);
```

Comment: Please, paste your code with `ref` and out. I believe you had made a mistake - see my last snippet.

Comment: @kopelence That is because you cannot pass one field of a class, if you want to update part of a class you will need to pass the entire class as a reference.

Comment: how to pass entire class as reference ?

Comment: Is `PreviousCalls` instance or `previousBot1Call` is static member?

Comment: It's in my question it's static member

Comment: Ahh I missed that, So you should use `ref`/`out` or create helper class (see my edit).

Comment: I like your answer i did it in a different way can you tell me if it's correct ? before i call the method i create a variable like this `int a = PreviousCalls.previousBot1Call;` after the method is over i set `PreviousCalls.previousBot1Call = previous` will this do the job ? I upvoted your's because you helped me the most

Comment: You attempt is good since `a` is passed as `ref` or `out` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly methods do not change any values outside of their method scope, instead they return a new value. Only methods that accept the parameter by reference instead of value can change the value of the parameter in the calling context.

[This article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx) is a great starting point for understanding how to pass parameters by reference instead of value.

Please note that you will not be able to pass a class member as a `ref` or `out` parameter. If you wish to update part of a class via reference, you will need to pass the entire class object as the reference.